# StreamBuilder returns error after updating flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

After updatig flutter I encountered a problem within StreamBuilder.
The line marked with ** returns error. I tried to correct it by adding null-check (!) but it returns:

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.

How can I solve it?

In addition, is there a more elegant way (Aka, without StreamBuilder) to take snapshots/streams?
For example, I noticed that the following code line is valid:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("campdata").doc(docId).snapshots();
```

However, I do not know how to further develop it so it returns readable data from firebase.

Many thanks

```
  strem_builder_matcheduser(){
      return StreamBuilder(
          stream: firestore.collection("Requests").doc(matched_user_mail).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final messages = snapshot.data;
              matched_user_connectionstatus = **messages['status of connection']**;
            }
            if(matched_user_connectionstatus=="offline"){
    
              try{
              }catch(e){}
              return SizedBox();
            }
            else
              return Text("");
          }
      );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
matched_user_connectionstatus = messages.get('status of connection');
```

Or this:

```
final messages = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
matched_user_connectionstatus = messages['status of connection'];
```

Comment: snapshot.data.data() is not valid I made:

              final messages = snapshot.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
              matched_user_connectionstatus = messages['status of connection'];     

But it returns an error:
type '_JsonDocumentSnapshot' us not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type case

Comment: I edited my answer, try it now, you need to use `data()`, so go for `snapshot.data()` instead of data.data()

Comment: final messages = snapshot.data() is neither valid. I tried snapshot.data but it returned an error, as mentioned before

Answer (score 0):

one tip, always when you are using FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder, always set a condition where the information is for example loading. because to get information from firebase takes time, it's not immediately, you have to set a condiction when information is loading otherwise could give an error

```
if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
   return ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar();
 }
```

Comment: I will take it into account thank you